# Forge Viewer - How can I output the meshes information log?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am now using the most updated version of forger viewer js.

As the **three.min.js** is no longer required since viewer version v5, How can I output the followings information in the console?

Thanks.

```
three.min.js:2 Total geometry size: 2.0363502502441406 MB
three.min.js:2 Number of meshes: 145
three.min.js:2 Num Meshes on GPU: 144
three.min.js:2 Net GPU geom memory used: 2068452
three.min.js:2 THREE.WebGLRenderer 71
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to support viewing large (especially architecture and infrastructure) models, the memory management in Forge Viewer is quite complex. Geometries may be moved on and off the GPU during runtime, and even the number of geometries in memory can change over time. Because of this, I'm afraid the stats you get from three.js aren't very reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just discovered that the logs appears only in small models. For large models, I am going to use the default memory manager extension from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824244/forge-viewer-crashes-after-loading-specific-model). Is this stats more reliable? However, I cannot find any documentation about this extension that what is the meaning of each tracking items is about (eg. Pack File Count, Last Page Out, etc). Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: That extension is mostly used by the dev team for debugging (so unfortunately there's no public documentation), but yes, you'll find more reliable stats there.

Comment: Regarding the different terms used in the extension: pack files are a simple binary format that the viewer uses to store geometry data. There may be multiple pack files available for a single URN, and those can be downloaded or evicted from memory ("Paged Out") during runtime.